# Does the many worlds interpretation require a 100% spin up branch?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

In his Q&A after his Brief History of Quantum Mechanics talk Sean Caroll mentioned that when writing his book he made 50 quantum spin measurements for an example. He admitted that in some universe he would have measured them all spin up. Then he shrugged it off like it wasn't a big deal and he would have just thought someone broke the machine.

Does that mean that in some branch of the universe there is a poor physicist that has only and will only ever measure spin up? In fact you could go even further and say every physicist there only ever measured spin up. They would think quantum mechanics is entirely flawed or broken.

Should this not bother me, are there reasons it wouldn't happen, or ways around the issue?

Link to the timestamp of the video: [Spin up every time](https://youtu.be/Jv5FYrOthvE?t=1339)

Comment: The many worlds interpretation includes worlds in which the statistics of measurement do not work out in a persons lifetime to the mean value implied by quantum mechanics. A physcist in such a world could not come to the quantum theory by induction. The many worlds interpretation does not explain, in and of itself, why we should be living in a universe that does provide statistics that match the mean behaviours of quantum theory. All such attempts include some kind of quantum ergodic assumption, or an as yet unsuccessful attempt to prove one from a simpler principle.

Answer (score 0):

The laws of momentum conservation, angular momentum conservation, charge conservation, etc., still hold in all of the many worlds branches, so if all particles are spin up in one of the branches, the resulting "gained" angular momentum would need to be balanced by opposite angular momentum in some other form.

Comment: Right, I understand that not every particle in that universe would be spin up. The particles that are measured consecutively in a lab do have a chance to all be measured as spin up though. Everything else would work fine, but the experimenters would forever be confused.

Comment: Hopefully that unlucky experimenter would blame that unlikely sequence of events on some sort of experimental bias.  Then he/she could look for astronomical evidence.  It ought to show up in a myriad of ways.  For example, atomic spectra would be hugely different if all electrons had the same spin orientation.